# SQL search full time or partial time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a stored procedure that can filter on a full or partial time. It should only filter on hours or minutes (not seconds) or both hours and minutes.

Using the sample data below:

1. `@StartTimeFilter  = '09:15'` --> should return record #1
2. `@StartTimeFilter = '10'` --> should return records 2, 3, 10
3. `@StartTimeFilter = '5'` --> should return records 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
4. `@StartTimeFilter = '45'` --> should return records 5, 6
5. `@StartTimeFilter = '13:45'` --> should return record #6
6. `@StartTimeFilter = '11:'` --> should return records 4, 5

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE test 
(
    id INT,
    startTime DateTime
);

INSERT INTO test (id, startTime) VALUES (1, '2021-10-25 09:15:00');
INSERT INTO test (id, startTime) VALUES (2, '2021-10-25 10:15:00');
INSERT INTO test (id, startTime) VALUES (3, '2021-10-25 10:30:00');
INSERT INTO test (id, startTime) VALUES (4, '2021-10-25 11:30:00');
INSERT INTO test (id, startTime) VALUES (5, '2021-10-25 11:45:00');
INSERT INTO test (id, startTime) VALUES (6, '2021-10-25 13:45:00');
INSERT INTO test (id, startTime) VALUES (7, '2021-10-25 14:50:00');
INSERT INTO test (id, startTime) VALUES (8, '2021-10-25 15:51:00');
INSERT INTO test (id, startTime) VALUES (9, '2021-10-25 15:58:00');
INSERT INTO test (id, startTime) VALUES (10,'2021-10-25 16:10:00');
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need a simple `like` string comparision:

```
declare @StartTimeFilter varchar(10)='5'

select *
from test
where Convert(varchar(5),starttime,114) like Concat('%',@StartTimeFilter,'%')
```